# Recursively create list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, tuples

I have code in PROLOG:

```
vals(_,[],_).
vals([H|T],[(H,C)|L],K) :- vals([H|T],L,(K,C)).
```

This code receivers list and list of tuples, for example:

```
 vals([1],[(1,4),(1,2)],X).
```

I check if element from first list is equal to some tuples first element from the other list. In this case foundValues will return true, because 1 is equal to each tuples first element. This works fine, but instead of returning true/false, in resulting list I want to return all second element of each tuple where its first element is equal to the element from list. In this case X should be [4,2]. I am trying to do this with (K,C), but no success.
So, the question is - How to return list?

Comment: Right now, your 3rd argument to `vals/3` doesn't really do anything. You could make it be the list you want. If the head of `[H|T]` matches the first element of the head of `[(H,C)|L]` what do you think the head of the 3rd argument should be? And where do you think the tail of the 3rd argument should come from (or how should it be determined)?

Comment: The head of third argument should be C, but I don't know how to recursively add elements to the list after each call.

Comment: The result then would look like `[C|R]`. You just have to tell it how to get the tail of the result (`R`) from the tails of the inputs. It's easier than you think.

Comment: Why is your first argument a list, while you are only using the head? Shouldn't you add a case when not all tupples in the second list start with 1 in your example?

Comment: This is a base case, list can also be longer and contain more elements.
And case when not all tuples in the second list start with 1:
vals([H|T],[(O,_)|L],K)) :- H\=O,foundValues2([H|T],L,K)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example on how to append to the list, just for 1 element.

Three cases:

- For an empty list
- When the element matches the first entry of the tupple
- When the element not matches

Starting from this you should be able to create your example.

```
vals(_,[],[]).
vals(H,[(H,C)|L],[C|K]) :- vals(H,L,K).
vals(H,[(H2,_)|L],K) :- 
    H \= H2,
    vals(H,L,K).
```

Example:

```
vals(1,[(1,2),(1,3)],X).
X = [2, 3] ;
false.
```

Extra:

- Consider placing a [cut](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse44) in case 2.
- Consider rewrite this with an [accumulator](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse20)

Comment: This predicate always returns `[]` if the first list has at least as many elements as the second, and fails if the first list is shorter than the second. The first argument `H` is incorrect in the 2nd and 3rd clauses. Also, why would one consider using an accumulator? Finally, why suggest a cut in case 2? It should use `dif(H, H2)` and no cut, which maintains a relational capability of the predicate.

Comment: Isn't it only returning an empty list when nothing there is nothing matched?

Comment: Nope. Did you try it? Try, for example, `vals([1,2], [(1,a), (3,b), (4,c)], L).`. The result should be `L = [a]`. The OP's example happens to only use a list of one element. But the description clearly says, *check if element from first list is equal to some tuples*...

Comment: I guess there is a misunderstanding of what I was trying to show. I updated my answer. I answered to the question "So, the question is - How to return list?". Without giving it all away.

Comment: The reason I would use a cut: the result remains, while the number of computations decreases. Not sure what you mean with "relational capability of the predicate"?

Comment: Thank you for help! This works fine, I will try to make it work also when the  first argument is list, not just a single element, as @lurker showed.